# Suppose $f$ continuous in $[a,b]$ and $g$ integrable and non negative in $[a,b]$ Prove: $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx=f(\xi)\int_{a}^{b}g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

i have problem with my proof of this theorem:

Suppose $f$ continuous in $[a,b]$ and $g$ integrable and non negative in $[a,b]$ Prove: $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx=f(\xi)\int_{a}^{b}g(x)$

I try this

Suppose $m\leq f(x)\leq M=m(g(x))\leq f(x)g(x)\leq M(g(x))\Rightarrow $ $m\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx\leq\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx\leq M\int_{a}^{b}g(x)$, Let $\mu=\frac{\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx}{\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx}$ , If we divide we get: $m\leq\frac{\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx}{\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx}\leq M $ and that equal to $m\leq\mu\leq M \Rightarrow$$m\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx\leq\mu\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\leq M\int_{a}^{b}g(x)$, if we take $\mu=f(\xi)$ then $f(\xi)\int_{a}^{b}g(x)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx$

Is fine my proof?

Comment: Why can we take $\mu = f(\xi)$?  It's a key part of the proof, you should justify it.

Comment: For Intermediate value theorem? @Mark

Comment: Yes...Good job!